# How to get the header from a CSV file and write it to another file?

Tags: windows, perl, powershell, cmd, header

How can I get the header from a CSV file and write it to another file ?
This code works if I don't have many columns in the CSV file, but it doesn't work when my CSV file contains 200+ columns. It just echoes the column header (but not all of them, they are truncated) to the screen.

```
@echo off
set /p "header="<book1.csv
echo %header% > "book3.csv"
```

Comment: (Get-Content book1.csv)[0] > book3.csv

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:perl]?

Comment: @MattJacob: I was wondering the same, so I replied.

Comment: I think the user wants someone to give him the code for any of those lnguages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running powershell you should be able to use the `-TotalCount` (aliases `-Head` and `-First`) parameter of `Get-Content` (alias `GC`) to just get the first line of a file.

```
gc book1.csv -head 1|sc book3.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = 'Text::CSV_XS'->new({binary => 1, escape_char => '\\'});
open my $fh, '<', 'book1.csv' or die $!;
my $h = $csv->getline($fh);

my $out = 'Text::CSV_XS'->new({eol => $/, escape_char => '\\'});
open my $fho, '>', 'book3.csv' or die $!;
$out->say($fho, $h);
```

Tested with

```
"Header 1","Header, 2","Header \"3\"","Header
4"
1,2,3,4
```